# Method of charactersitics and second order PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How may the method of characteristics be applied to solve a second order PDE? For instance, to solve the equation: $u_{tt}=u_{xx}-2u_t$.

Comment: Your PDE is very odd as both $u$ and $y$ are dependent variables.

Comment: I am terribly sorry! I just emended it.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is not suitable for displayng
the techniques called  *Method of characteristics*.
Nevertheless, if you really need this equation, you
can construct its general solution. To do this, first
substitute $\;u=ve^{-t}$,   then change variables 
$\;\xi=2(t+x)\;$, $\;\eta=2(t-x)\;$,
reducing your equation to the simplest possible form $\;v_{\xi\eta}-v=0\;$. 
General solution of the latter equation looks like
$$v(\xi,\eta)=\!\int\limits_0^{\xi}f(s)I_0\Bigl(2\sqrt{\eta(\xi-s)}\Bigr)\,ds
+\!\int\limits_0^{\eta}g(s)I_0\Bigl(2\sqrt{\xi(\eta-s)}\Bigr)\,ds
 \tag{$\ast$}$$
for arbitrarily given functions $f,g\in C^1$ with notation $\;I_0\;$ standing for the *zero order modified Bessel function of the first kind*.  
To obtain general solution $(\ast)$ apply the Laplace transform
$$
   \hat{f}(p)\overset{\rm def}{=}\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\int\limits_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-pt}dt
$$
to the equation $v_{\xi\eta}-v=0$   *w.r.t.*  any of the two variables,
say $\eta$, then integrate the equation $p\hat{v}_{\xi}-\hat{v}=v_{\xi}(\xi,0)
\overset{\rm not}{=}f(\xi)$    to find that
$$
\hat{v}(\xi,p)=\int\limits_0^{\xi}f(s)
\frac{e^{\frac{\xi-s}{p}}}{p}\,ds+ c(p)e^{\frac{\xi}{p}}.
$$
Since $\mathcal{L}\bigl[I_0\bigl(2\sqrt{\alpha t}\bigr)\bigr]=
\frac{1}{p}e^{\frac{\alpha}{p}}$, 
 the representation $(\ast)$ readily follows by 
choosing $c(p)=\hat{g}(p)/p$.  
Of course,   general solution $(\ast)$ looks rather complicated, but for the last two and a half centuries, nothing better has yet been found to replace it.

Comment: Could you please clarify how you arrived at $
\hat{v}(\xi,p)=\int\limits_0^{\xi}f(s)
\frac{e^{\frac{\xi-s}{p}}}{p}\,ds+ c(p)e^{\frac{\xi}{p}}.
$ from $p\hat{v}_{\xi}-\hat{v}=v_{\xi}(\xi,0)
\overset{\rm not}{=}f(\xi)$ thanks