# solving a partial differential equation PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to find the solution of
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
I know I can solve it if there were some initial conditions but 
I want to find the general solution for it, I tried a linear change of variable  but it didn't work.

Comment: This is heat equation.

Comment: Hint: Fundamental solution

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [PDE - solution with power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476472):

Let $u(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x-a)^n}{n!}\dfrac{\partial^nu(a,y)}{\partial x^n}$ ,

Then $u(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x-a)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\dfrac{\partial^{2n}u(a,y)}{\partial x^{2n}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\dfrac{\partial^{2n+1}u(a,y)}{\partial x^{2n+1}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x-a)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\dfrac{\partial^nu(a,y)}{\partial y^n}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\dfrac{\partial^{n+1}(a,y)}{\partial y^n\partial x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{f^{(n)}(y)(x-a)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{g^{(n)}(y)(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$